# Apache Pivot and custom ListView ItemRenderer

Tags: java, listview, apache-pivot

Say I want the following layout in my List View's items:

```
<TablePane styles = "{padding : 5, horizontalSpacing : 5, verticalSpacing : 5}" >
    <columns>
        <TablePane.Column width = "1*"/>
        <TablePane.Column width = "21"/>
    </columns>

    <TablePane.Row height="-1">
        <TextInput bxml:id ="txtName" 
                   textSize="15" />
        <TablePane.Filler/>
    </TablePane.Row>

    <TablePane.Row height="-1">
        <TablePane.Filler/>
        <ActivityIndicator active="true" width="16" height="16"/>
    </TablePane.Row>
</TablePane>
```

And say I have the following custom ItemRenderer:

```
public class CustomListRenderer extends TablePane
                                implements ListView.ItemRenderer {
    // stuff here
}
```

What is the best way to use the BXML snippet above with my custom ListRenderer?

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to do this is to make CustomListRenderer be what you might call the "code behind" for a similarly-named bxml file, and add a factory method to it to create itself by calling the bxml serializer.  Something like this:

```
public class CustomListRenderer extends TablePane
                                implements ListView.ItemRenderer {
    public static CustomListRenderer create() throws IOException, SerializationException {
    BXMLSerializer bxmlSerializer = new BXMLSerializer();
    return (CustomListRenderer) bxmlSerializer.readObject(CustomListRenderer.class, "CustomListRenderer.bxml");
    }

    // rest of your stuff here
}
```

Then put your snippet above into CustomListRenderer.bxml, but change the root item to be CustomListRenderer:

```
<my:CustomListRenderer styles = "{padding : 5, horizontalSpacing : 5, verticalSpacing : 5}" 
  xmlns:bxml="http://pivot.apache.org/bxml"
  xmlns:my="your.java.package.here"
  xmlns="org.apache.pivot.wtk">
  ... rest of your bxml here ...
```

Finally, when you create the ListView that wants to use your custom renderer, you can do

```
listview.setItemRenderer(CustomListRenderer.create());
```